# How to log out a user from a GWT application?

Tags: java, security, gwt

I develop an GWT applicationwith HTTP basic login type.

I have a "Logout" button that calls a server side method logout()

```
public void logout() {
  getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().invalidate();

}
```

after the call it executes

```
 Cookies.removeCookie("JSESSIONID");
 Window.Location.reload();
```

in order to reload the page and get a browser's login screen.

But when the page reloads, I'm still logged in. Why ?

Comment: How are you checking whether user is logged in or not? Please paste the code where you do that check.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Logout is a common problem for basic HTTP authentication.

Ref. [Logout with http basic authentication and restful_authentication plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660155/logout-with-http-basic-authentication-and-restful-authentication-plugin)

> if the user logs in with basic auth, he/she will have to close his/her browser window to logout.