# How to forget basic authentication details in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, basic-authentication

This is very similar to << [How to clear basic authentication details in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957822/how-to-clear-basic-authentication-details-in-chrome) >> but the accepted answer there is unsatisfactory because it only allows you to try a different username/password, it doesn't allow you to tell Chrome to forget the username/password.

I've looked in the settings and see the ability to clear saved username/password pairs (`Passwords and forms > Manage saved passwords`), but I can't find a way to clear HTTP Auth pairs.  This is a security issue if I log into a http-auth protected site on a public or shared computer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a web browser, not programming. (That said, have you tried using incognito mode while on public computers?)

Comment: @Michelle you are right, I only posted here because the similar answer was also on this SO site. I'd also wager that the most common use of Http Auth is to protect development versions of websites.