# How to allow input username and password each time when requesting a webpage in Chrome using apache basic .htaccess authenticatoin?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, authentication

I encountered a problem when using the basic authentication with Apache .htaccess with Google Chrome. In my directory of domain, I have a .htaccess with the following:

```
AuthName "Auth Test"
AuthUserFile /home/user/.passwd
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

When I test the result with IE and Firefox, they work fine, every time requesting the webpage after closing the browser and open it again, it prompts for username and password. But this does not happen in Google Chrome, after input username and password the first time, it will not prompt again even I closed all the browser, logout and login again, or even reboot. The only exception is using incognito mode.

What I want is the user needs to input the username and password each time they open the browser and browse my webpage.

Does anyone come across this? Thanks in advance for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

This problem isn't server side.  It's about how chrome cache pages.  It is caching the authentication and you need to clear browse history to be asking the password again.

Using incognito mode also helps.

This thread there are options to the same problem: [How to clear basic authentication details in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957822/how-to-clear-basic-authentication-details-in-chrome)