# Sending 'Authorization' header in Ext JS Ajax Request, Chrome vs. Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, extjs

In code the request is sent as:

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    url: 'someUrl',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        ...
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
};

    var form = this.getView().getForm();
    var submitAction = Ext.create('Ext.form.action.Submit', { form: form });
    var formInfo = submitAction.buildForm();
    ajaxOptions.form = formInfo.formEl;
    if (form.hasUpload()) {
        ajaxOptions.isUpload = true;
    }
    Ext.Ajax.request(ajaxOptions);
```

When a request is sent via Chrome, the 'Authorization' header presents:

```
Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

When it is sent via Firefox, the header is not included.
Explicitely I don't set user/password. So it's not clear, why and how chrome sends such header. Are there any known issues?
The second, how to force firefox to send such header? Is it possible?

**UPDATED**
JavaScript does not now anything about login/password. The main question, how Chrome can use them, but other browsers cannot send such pair. So the question is how to force other browsers to send this cookie as Chrome does without appling headers manually via JavaScript.

On the server side, the Servlet API is used.  in web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>someName</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

if it does matter

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request), just add a `headers` property to your `ajaxOptions`:

```
ajaxOptions = {
    //...
    headers : {
        'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
    }
}
```

Comment: @arthurokay: JavaScript does not now anything about login/password. The main question, how Chrome can use them, but other browsers cannot send such pair. So the question is how to force other browsers to send this cookie as Chrome does without appling headers manually.

Comment: If that's the question, then perhaps Chrome has some user/pass cached for that domain. Try running the app in an "incognito" window to verify -- or perhaps try to [clear any user/pass settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957822/how-to-clear-basic-authentication-details-in-chrome). No browser should send an "Authorization" header unless there are user/pass to send!

Comment: In other words, I don't think Ext JS is adding that header -- I think the Chrome injects it.