# Basic HTTP Auth - wget with Cookies

Tags: linux, shell, authentication, wget

I am currrently using the following command to retrieve data from a site:

```
wget http://www.example.com --user=joe --password=schmoe --auth-no-challenge
```

I expand this to be recursive, however, my understanding is that this will resend the HTTP Auth credentials on each request.

Hence, is it possible to run the Basic HTTP Auth once, capture the cookies, and then trigger a recursive load with those cookies?

This does not appear to work:

```
wget --save-cookies=cookies.txt --user=joe --password=schmoe --auth-no-challenge http://www.example.com
```

Followed by:

```
 wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt -r -p http://www.example.com/pages.html
```

Answer (score 3):

The [HTTP Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) authentication scheme is [not a persistent, cookie-based authentication scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HTTP_authentication), like say a [Bearer](http://tools.ietf.org/html/6750) scheme (e.g. Oauth2), so the credentials will need to be passed on **all** subsequent requests. The exception would be at the "*application*" layer if the browser caches the credentials, but that is a browser convenience construct (one of which there is [minimal control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957822/how-to-clear-basic-authentication-details-in-chrome) over) and wouldn't apply in this situation with `wget`.

> [Here](https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/) is a good summary of the [drawbacks](https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/#gist28248726) of HTTP Basic, **including** the fact that credentials need to be sent with **every** request.

Check out the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Authentication Scheme Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) for a comprehensive list of authentication schemes.