# Private PyPI Server Error: 403 Forbidden When Accessing Index Page

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pypi

I created a private PyPi server on AWS, when I tried to access it I put in my password but I believe I put in the wrong one. Ever since then if I try to go to the list of packages [the home page of Welcome to PyPi loads fine] i get a 403 error [screenshot attached].

[image]

I logged into the EC2 instance via ssh and restarted the docker container inside which the server is running but that did not help. I can still upload packages to the server [I was able to remember my credentials] and the count does increase on the welcome page when I do, but I just cant seem to look at the index page with all the packages.

On trying to download a package I get this error:

```
  Cannot unpack file /private/var/folders/ts/dh6k_f1d1q9db9kzcdpky0600000gp/T/pip-unpack-_ggo02m4/packages (downloaded from /private/var/folders/ts/dh6k_f1d1q9db9kzcdpky0600000gp/T/pip-req-build-n7mq4td_, content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of /private/var/folders/ts/dh6k_f1d1q9db9kzcdpky0600000gp/T/pip-req-build-n7mq4td_
```

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/68539251/7195666